# Thread synchronization between a slow and a fast processing thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, image-processing, multiprocessing, pipe

I'm working on automation of a vision based machine driven by stepper motor. Structure of my program is as followed.

```
import ImageProcessing
import Mechanices
import cv2

def rotate_motor(steps,direction):
    global g_motor_ploc

    DIR = 20  # Direction GPIO Pin
    STEP = 21  # Step GPIO Pin
    delay = .00055

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(DIR, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(STEP, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(DIR, direction)

    for x in range(steps):
        GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(delay)
        GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(delay)
    GPIO.cleanup()

def findImage():
    ####################################
    < Very Fast Image Processing Code >
    ####################################
    return position_of_object

def calculate_steps(position):
    ####################################
    < Very Fast Steps and Direction Calculation Code >
    ####################################
    return steps_required,direction_of_rotation

def main():
    while True:
        position=findImage()
        steps, direction = calculate_steps 
        rotate_motor(steps,directions)          # Very Slow Process

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Despite very fast processing of images, whole program has to wait for `rotate_motor` to complete before processing next frame. In mean time if object moves backward it fails to see the change unless previously calculated position is achieved.

I'm looking forward to run `rotate_motor` in a separate thread and update the number_of_steps and direction required for motion. So that even if previously calculated position is not achieved, it should know how many more steps are required or change of direction is required.

So I modified the program as followed:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2

(r, g_w) = mp.Pipe(True)
g_motor_ploc = 0

def rotate_motor(steps,direction):
    global g_motor_ploc

    DIR = 20  # Direction GPIO Pin
    STEP = 21  # Step GPIO Pin
    delay = .00055

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(DIR, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(STEP, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(DIR, direction)

    for x in range(steps):
        GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(delay)
        GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(delay)
        if direction==1:
            g_motor_ploc -= 1
        else:
            g_motor_ploc += 1
    GPIO.cleanup()

def findImage():
    ####################################
    < Very Fast Image Processing Code >
    ####################################
    return position_of_object

def calculate_steps(position):
    ####################################
    < Very Fast Steps and Direction Calculation Code >
    ####################################
    return steps_required,direction_of_rotation ## (Clockwise, Counter Clockwise)

def linear_motion(r):
    global g_motor_ploc
    while True:
        loc = r.recv()
        steps = loc - g_motor_ploc
        if steps < 0:
            direction = 1
        else:
            direction = 0
        rotate_motor(abs(steps),direction)

def main():
    while True:
        position=findImage()
        steps = calculate_steps 
        g_w.send(steps)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    motor_proc = mp.Process(target=linear_motion, args=(r,))
    motor_proc.daemon = True
    motor_proc.start()
    main()
```

Using the `mp.Pipe()` it interrupts the `linear_motion()` as soon as new position is send to the pipe. However this process if so fast that `linear_motion` never reach to the `rotate_motor` part.

## Any suggestions, I'm confused.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code, but I'm not sure which bit is causing you problems. Maybe the real problem is that the pipe does **not** interrupt `linear_motion`. Your `main()` will cycle round really quickly filling the pipe with new `steps`. `linear_motion()` cycles round really slowly only taking one item from the pipe each time. It will just get further and further behind `main()`.